# DBMS_OUTPUT PL SQL code in Oracle sql developer not show the output

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

Running this, I see no output other than 'completed'

```
set serveroutput on
declare
 message varchar2(20) := 'Hello, World';
begin
 dbms_output.put_line(message);
end;
/
```

Comment: In Oracle sql developer the output not show after put set serveroutput on comment.

Comment: The window **contains** SET SERVEROUTPUT ON. But, did you actually **execute** it before running that PL/SQL block?

Comment: Was the "Dbms Output" pane already open and connected when you ran it; and did you click 'run statement' or 'run script'?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this behavior before, and it's always because your database is too old.

Are you using something older than 11gR2 on the database? If so, our newer jdbc drivers no longer support DMBS_OUTPUT polling on 9i and 10g of the Database.

Your options are:

1. find an older copy of SQL Developer, which uses an older JDBC driver or
2. Upgrade your database to something from this decade (19c would be best)

Obviously option 1 is the easiest and option 2 is the most desirable.